# Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reportviewer, rdlc

i m using ASP.NET MVC. now i needed RDLC report so i used reportviewer. but i dont want to use iframe so i did routing in my global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            //Custom route for reports
            routes.MapPageRoute(
             "ReportRoute",                         // Route name
             "Reports/{reportname}",                // URL
             "~/CommonReports/{reportname}.aspx"   // File
             );

        }
```

my jquery code is

```
$('#hrfItemSoldRpt').live('click', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Retail_MVC/Reports/ReportViewer',
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
    });
```

now its on my Content but no css apply, no any click its just in disabled format

i got this in alert and also in responce HTML but it gives error

```
 Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts
```

is there any solution please??

Comment: Have you disabled JavaScript on your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about loading  RDLC report from Jquery ajax then its not possible because RDLC Report is a Asp.net server side control and you are trying to render it as a html from client side.

You need to either use iframe or any other option to fulfill your requirment

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below link for solution
http://dobrzanski.net/2008/08/07/reporting-services-your-browser-does-not-support-scripts-or-has-been-configured-not-to-allow-scripts/